# How to add mime-type for <video> element on Firefox?

Tags: apache, firefox, video, html, mime-types

Into [this dir](http://media.pianotage.com/video/) there are :

- OGV video (Theora/Vorbis) for Firefox
- MP4 video (H264/AAC) for Safari
- FLV video with a flash player (player.swf) for others browsers
- a template.html which contains a snippet coming from [Video for everybody](http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody#video-code)
- a .htaccess to add the new types of video

Locally the video is correctly displayed on *all* browsers.
But online Firefox doesn't display the video and ask for a download. Though the mime-type is correctly set in my .htaccess.

Any idea to fix this problem on Firefox ? (I use 3.5.3 release on Windows).

Thank you. :)

Note: it sounds that this problem doesn't appear on Ubuntu.

**Edit** : my Firefox installation was bugged. Now it's working correctly. Thank you Rudism. :)

Comment: Just tried template.html in FireFox 3.5.5 on Windows XP and the video displayed and played correctly for me. The ogv file is coming back from the server with Content-Type: video/ogg.

Comment: Wow, this is strange. My firefox may be bugged ? I will reinstall it. Thank you for your comment. ;)

Answer (score 1):

It may be worth trying it in Google Chrome which support video/ogg as well. May help you debug...